# Dictionary Unhandled Exception in C#: "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, exception

I'm trying to print out a dictionary in C# that will simulate a graph. My dictionary looks like this:

`Dictionary<int, List<int>> graph = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();`

In main, I add something to the dictionary, then try to print it out:

```
        dicOfLists myDic = new dicOfLists();

        myDic.AddEdge(1, 2);
        myDic.printList();
```

The methods `AddEdge` and `PrintList` are pretty straightforward:

AddEdge:

```
    public void AddEdge(int v1, int v2)
    {
        if (graph[v1] == null)
        {
            graph[v1] = new List<int> { v2 };
            return;
        }
        graph[v1].Add(v2);
    }
```

PrintList:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(graph[i][i]);
        }
```

I haven't done much programming in C# or Python, so dictionaries are new to me. I think why I'm getting tripped up is more conceptual than anything, specifically because I'm not sure how a list works within a dictionary.

The way I currently understand it is as follows:

Upon calling `Addedge(1, 2)` my dictionary is creating a list with a single element `2` at position `1` of my dictionary. This is because the first parameter represents the dictionary's key, and the second represents the list. The key functions like it would in a hashtable. When the key is provided, the dictionary looks at that position, and then creates a list.

Like I said, I'm new to C# so please don't skewer me too hard. While this might be something trivial like a straightforward syntax error, I'm not able to find much of anything for this specific problem online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try replacing `if (graph[v1] == null)` with `if (!graph.ContainsKey(v1))`

Comment: @Kevin Gosse My error changes slightly with that. I'm now getting "The given key '0' was not present in the dictionary." Before I was getting ""The given key '1' was not present in the dictionary."

Comment: Your `PrintList` is trying to access an element with key `0` - but as the error states, you never added one (you only added one with key `1`)

Comment: @UnholySheep I see what you're saying, but if I change my call to `myDic.AddEdge(0, 1);`, I still get the same error. Did I miss something you were saying?

Comment: What is dicOfLists?

Answer (score 0):

You've got one method adding key/values to a dictionary and another printing them. The method printing them doesn't "know" what's been inserted, so it's better if that method doesn't make any assumptions about what's in the dictionary. Instead of just looping through a series of possible keys (0 to 1, 0 to *n*, etc.) it's better to operate according to what actually is in the dictionary.

```
var keys = graph.Keys;

// or, if you they were entered out of sequence and you want to sort them
var keys = graph.Keys.OrderBy(k => k);

// Now you're using the actual keys that are in the dictionary, so you'll never
// try to access a missing key.

foreach(var key in keys)
{
    // It's not quite as clear to me what you're doing with these objects.
    // Suppose you wanted to print out everything:

    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {key}");

    foreach(var value in graph[key])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }        
}
```